# Stored Procedure Error "Encountered EOF when expecting

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, stored-functions

So, I've done some researching and from what I can find of similar problems, I cannot solve my particular issue.  I'm encountering the dreaded,

> Error(35,18): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit for all    merge pipe purge

Some of the fixes were to look through your code and find any left off semi-colons.  The problem with that for my particular code is that without the declaration as a stored procedure and the IN parameter, the code works perfectly.  I'm taking a procedure that works and just trying to be able to change what is being searched without hardcoding a whole new search.  Does that make sense?

Here is the code:  `

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testProcedure(var_Name IN varchar2)
IS
BEGIN
DECLARE
    var_Name newscores.name%TYPE;
    var_courseNo newscores.courseNo%Type;
    var_sectionNo newscores.sectionNo%Type;
    var_average grade2.average%TYPE;
    var_termscores gradepolicy.lettergrade%TYPE;
CURSOR AverageCursor is
    SELECT distinct n.name, n.courseNo, n.sectionNo, g2.average, gp.lettergrade
from newscores n, grade2 g2, gradepolicy gp
where n.stuNo = g2.stuNo
and n.courseNo = g2.courseNo
and n.sectionNo = g2.sectionNo
and g2.average < gp.upper_bound
and g2.average > gp.low_bound
and n.name = 'Randy Ballard'
and gp.classNo = g2.courseNo
and gp.sectionNo = g2.sectionNo;
BEGIN
OPEN AverageCursor;
LOOP

    FETCH AverageCursor
      INTO var_Name, var_courseNo, var_SectionNo, var_average, var_termscore;
    Exit when AverageCursor%NOTFOUND;

    dbms_output.put_line('Full Name'||' '||var_Name);
    dbms_output.put_line('Full Name'||' '||var_courseNo);
    dbms_output.put_line('Full Name'||' '||var_sectionNo);
    dbms_output.put_line('Full Name'||' '||var_average);
    dbms_output.put_line('Full Name'||' '||var_termscore);
END LOOP;
END testProcedure;
/
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DECLARE` keyword and extra `BEGIN` are causing your error. Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testProcedure(p_name IN VARCHAR2)
IS
    var_Name newscores.name%TYPE;
    var_courseNo newscores.courseNo%Type;
    var_sectionNo newscores.sectionNo%Type;
    var_average grade2.average%TYPE;
    var_termscores gradepolicy.lettergrade%TYPE;
    CURSOR AverageCursor is
        SELECT distinct n.name, n.courseNo, n.sectionNo, g2.average, gp.lettergrade
          from newscores n, grade2 g2, gradepolicy gp
          where n.stuNo = g2.stuNo
            and n.courseNo = g2.courseNo
            and n.sectionNo = g2.sectionNo
            and g2.average < gp.upper_bound
            and g2.average > gp.low_bound
            and n.name = p_name
            and gp.classNo = g2.courseNo
            and gp.sectionNo = g2.sectionNo;
BEGIN
  OPEN AverageCursor;
  LOOP

      FETCH AverageCursor
        INTO var_Name, var_courseNo, var_SectionNo, var_average, var_termscore;
      Exit when AverageCursor%NOTFOUND;

      dbms_output.put_line('Full Name'||' '||var_Name);
      dbms_output.put_line('Full Name'||' '||var_courseNo);
      dbms_output.put_line('Full Name'||' '||var_sectionNo);
      dbms_output.put_line('Full Name'||' '||var_average);
      dbms_output.put_line('Full Name'||' '||var_termscore);
  END LOOP;
END testProcedure;
/
```

Normally you declare your variables between the `IS` and the `BEGIN` keywords.

Comment: That generates the following error: 
Error(1,1): PLS-00410: duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted

Comment: @nmaybyte It's because you had procedure parameter with the same name as one of the variables. Check my edited answer, I have removed the parameter from the procedure. If you want it to be there, change its name.

Comment: Alright, let me pick your brain.  Apparently, you knowledge of this topic is much deeper than my own.  I'm sure you can tell that by looking at the cursor this procedure returns all the classes and the averages of said class that the student 'Randy Ballard' is attending.  Say I wanted to be able to use the procedure and allow the user to change the name of the searched person at will.  So, instead of Randy Ballard, say we want to search for Jane Downer.  How would I do this? I thought by using the IN parameter at the beginning I could achieve this goal.

Comment: @nmaybyte Look at my edited answer - solution is simple - I've added parameter to the procedure and, instead of hardcoded 'Randy Ballard' value, I use the argument in the cursor. This way, you can get info for different users, depending on the parameter that you passed to the procedure.

Comment: Thank you so much man.  I greatly appreciate not only your knowledge but also your curt and timely responses.

Comment: One last question.  If I wanted to do two inputs into this procedure, how would I do that?

Comment: @nmaybyte `PROCEDURE testProcedure(p_name IN VARCHAR2, another_param IN some_type)`, then use that another_param where you need.